# mod_rewrite VS relative paths

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

My mod_rewrite code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

This structure is placed on my server path `/beta`

When I place the URL `http://mydomain.com/beta/download` everything works rewriting to the real path `http://mydomain.com/beta/index.php?url=download`

The problem happens with the relative paths. When I enter the URL `http://mydomain.com/beta/download/box` the rewriting goes to `http://mydomain.com/beta/index.php?url=download/box`...  but....

All my relative paths, like my css folder, my js folder, image files....  everything with relative path in my index.php page crashes, cuz my relative paths become `download/css`, `download/js`, `download/images`... etc...

I know this problem happens in reason of the slash in the path "download/", but how can I solve that using the mod_rewrite in .htaccess?

Can I prevent rewriting in relative paths? Or even in internal paths of my own domain?

How can I solve that WITHOUT change my relative paths to absolute paths?

Thanks

Comment: Add a <base href="http://www.yoururl.com/beta/" /> tag to your HTML head. Also add RewriteBase /beta/ to the htaccess if you're in that subfolder.

Comment: May I know what is the relative URI you are using to access js and css files?

Comment: @PENDO great solution my friend!!!!! It's exactly what I was looking for!! Simple and efficient.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `<base href="yoururl.com/beta/"; />` tag to your HTML head. Also add RewriteBase /beta/ to the htaccess if you're in that subfolder

Comment: and make sure its added right after HTML head tag, and not after CSS and js paths.

Answer (score 1):

you should always use absolute paths for images css etc, when playing with mod_rewrite but simple solution might be to ignore css,js, images and rest in `RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC]`

```
RewriteRule ((js|css|images)\/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

however this might not work if these dirs actually depend of the current url

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the  tag and there's no need to indicate http:// The following code worked for me:

```
<base href="<?php echo dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The server won't ever know whtether the request came via relative or absolute path so there is nothing You can do about it. As stated in another answer, You could make exceptions but maintaining all of them etc will become PITA at some point. ;)

I always use absolute paths especially when rewriting so I'd suggest just that, it's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line:

```
<BASE href="http://www.sitename.com/">
```

to my page inside the `<head>` tag works great for me. It can be coded even a PHP function to automatize this so you don't have to bother with copy/paste on other occasions.

**Update:**

```
<?php
$BaseDir = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 0, strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
?>

<head>
...
<BASE href="<?php echo $BaseDir; ?>">
...
</head>
```