# mod_rewrite with relative paths

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My following `.htaccess` works fine in my local environment. It is located in `http://myexample.com/subdirectory-1/subdirectory-2/`. However I want it to also work on my webserver which obviously has a different domain. Can anybody help to adjust the below code to make in work on any domain?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# If cookie 'de'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://myexample.com/subdirectory-1/subdirectory-2/de [R=301]

# If cookie 'en'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://myexample.com/subdirectory-1/subdirectory-2/en [R=301]

# If browser language 'de'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://myexample.com/subdirectory-1/subdirectory-2/de [R=301]

# Else
RewriteRule ^$ http://myexample.com/subdirectory-1/subdirectory-2/en [R=301]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite VS relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333834/mod-rewrite-vs-relative-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic `RewriteBase` and use same set of rules both in localhost and on live server:

```
RewriteEngine On

# generate rewritebase and store in BASE env variable
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

# If cookie 'en' or 'de'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (en|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{ENV:BASE}%1 [L,R=301]

# If browser language 'de'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{ENV:BASE}de [R=301]

# Else
RewriteRule ^$ %{ENV:BASE}en [L,R=301]
```